# java swing -Create a button like carousel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, carousel

I would like to ask your help to get me started in creating a carousel like button list in java swing.  Is there any tutorial/ example or links you can provide me to get me started. I would like to create 15 buttons that can be scrollable from left to right only 10 buttons will be visible and the rest will be scrolled just like a carousel in

Thanks

Comment: *"the rest will be scrolled just like a carousel in.."*  Lose your merry-go-round (train) of thought, there?

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate a JScrollPane. If you put a panel inside a scroll pane and make that panel sufficiently wide (by, in this case, placing more buttons horizontally than can fit physically on the viewable width), then the scroll pane will automatically provide a bar that will scroll the inner panel left and right.

Answer (score 2):

This could be start
http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html It describes sliding one component but you can extend it.